# aws_wafv2_web_acl allow AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet (AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet)

Tags: terraform, amazon-waf

I have this AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet with a count statement available and need to add another statement by allowing SizeRestrictions_BODY. prepared this tf but when applied it is the plan shows that the rules added and then removed in the terraform run.

tf:

```
rule {
    name     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
    priority = 0
    override_action {
      none {}
    }
    statement {
      managed_rule_group_statement {
        name        = "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
        vendor_name = "AWS"
        rule_action_override {
          action_to_use {
            count {
              custom_request_handling {
                insert_header {
                  name  = "tfapv4"
                  value = "noloop"
                }
              }
            }
          }
          name = "CrossSiteScripting_BODY"
        }
        rule_action_override {
          name = "SizeRestrictions_BODY"
          action_to_use {
            allow {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
+ rule {
          + name     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
          + priority = 0

          + override_action {

              + none {}
            }

          + statement {

              + managed_rule_group_statement {
                  + name        = "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
                  + vendor_name = "AWS"

                  + rule_action_override {
                      + name = "CrossSiteScripting_BODY"

                      + action_to_use {

                          + count {
                              + custom_request_handling {
                                  + insert_header {
                                      + name  = "tfapv4"
                                      + value = "noloop"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  + rule_action_override {
                      + name = "SizeRestrictions_BODY"

                      + action_to_use {
                          + allow {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

          + visibility_config {
              + cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
              + metric_name                = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
              + sampled_requests_enabled   = true
            }
        }
      - rule {
          - name     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet" -> null
          - priority = 0 -> null

          - override_action {

              - none {}
            }

          - statement {

              - managed_rule_group_statement {
                  - name        = "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet" -> null
                  - vendor_name = "AWS" -> null

                  - rule_action_override {
                      - name = "CrossSiteScripting_BODY" -> null

                      - action_to_use {

                          - count {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  - rule_action_override {
                      - name = "SizeRestrictions_BODY" -> null

                      - action_to_use {
                          - allow {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

          - visibility_config {
              - cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true -> null
              - metric_name                = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet" -> null
              - sampled_requests_enabled   = true -> null
            }
        }
```

Require a solution to add multiple statements with 1 count and 1 allow.